# Firestore Querying a collection with a sub collection

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm stuck and needed help. I want to retrieve data from my Firestore database and display it to my Firestore recycler adapter. But my problem is, my query only retrieves the document after the root collection.

this is the structure of my Firestore database

- Product (Collection)

  - product name,price (Document)

    - Photos (Collection)

      - image_url (Document)

Here is my query

```
query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("Product", Constants.PRODUCT_NAME);
```

What I want to achieve is, also to retrieve my Photos collection from a single document and display it to my Firestore recyclerview.

Comment: As Huthaifa Muayyad pointed out in his answer, you have to perform two separate queries. All the queries in Firestore are shallow, it can only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and a sub-collections in a single query

Comment: You're very welcome, Patrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run two separate queries.

```
query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("Product", Constants.PRODUCT_NAME);
```

After this, you will know the DocumentID, you need to use this docId to point to the sub-collection, this is the pseudo code:

```
collectionReference.doc('ID from previous query').collection('Photos');
```